How can i get my email message ids using graph explorer and azure cli?
I am tryig to get my deleted email to permanently delete them. I can login no problem and the do the following
$USER_EMAIL = "test1@test.com"
az login
$TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com --client-id 
$CLIENT_ID --client-secret $CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID --query accessToken -o tsv)

$deletedEmailIds=$(curl -s -X GET 
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$USER_EMAIL/mailFolders/deletedItems/messages" -H 
"Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" | jq -r '.value[].id') 

The issue is that when it tries to run the curl cmd it gives an error
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test1@test.com/mailFolders/deletedItems/messages'.

How can i get this to work ?
Or is there already a Powershell script that does all of this ? Or can i do it in Azure ?

Could you confirm what response you are getting when you run the query in Graph Explorer?

I have not run in graph explorer. I am trying to do it via powershell

What API permissions you granted in your app registration? Could you include that Portal image?

Initially, I registered one application and granted Mail.ReadBasic.All permission of Application type as below:

To get deleted email message IDs of user with Graph API calls and Azure CLI service principal authentication, you can make use of below modified script:
$USER_EMAIL = "user@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$TENANT_ID = "tenantId"
$CLIENT_ID = "appId"
$CLIENT_SECRET = "secret"

az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions --tenant $TENANT_ID --username $CLIENT_ID --password $CLIENT_SECRET
$TOKEN = az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph --query 'accessToken' --output tsv

$deletedFolder = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$USER_EMAIL/mailFolders" -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $TOKEN" }).value | Where-Object { $_.displayName -eq "Deleted Items" }
$deletedFolderId = $deletedFolder.id

$deletedEmailIds = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$USER_EMAIL/mailFolders/$deletedFolderId/messages" -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $TOKEN" }).value | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id

Write-Output "Deleted Email IDs:"
$deletedEmailIds | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }

Response:

Alternatively, you can make use of below direct script by installing Microsoft Graph PowerShell module to fetch deleted email ids like this:
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Mail

$USER_EMAIL = "user@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$TENANT_ID = "tenantId"
$CLIENT_ID = "appId"
$CLIENT_SECRET = "secret"

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $CLIENT_SECRET -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($CLIENT_ID, $SecurePassword)
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TENANT_ID -Credential $Credential

$deletedFolder = Get-MgUserMailFolder -UserId $USER_EMAIL | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Deleted Items" }
$deletedFolderId = $deletedFolder.Id

$deletedEmailIds = Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage -UserId $USER_EMAIL -MailFolderId $deletedFolderId -Property "id" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id

Write-Output "Deleted Email IDs:`n$($deletedEmailIds -join "`n")"

Response:


seems to only get 10 emails and they are not deleted from the deleted folder . I hade 500 deleted emails in the deleted folder. When i ran the script it still had  500. Also i ran the script about 30 times

10 is the default page size and the example above just lists emails it doesn't delete them. If you want list all emals then Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage has both a  -PageSize 999 and -All parameter you can use to delete email use Remove-MgUserMessage.  Note even if you do delete emails this way they won't be permanently deleted they will go into the recoverable items folder so while they won't be visible to the user they will still be recoverable (this is the normal retention processes for anything that is deleted from a Mailbox).

can i also delete the recoverable items folder ?

Please post a new question regarding that and share link here

there's a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-permanentDelete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http in Beta note that still retains the item but it just out of reach of the users.

Hi @Natalie Any update?
